# How to avoid full table scan in SQL (using comma separated string, IN clause)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

My requirement is to pass comma separated string to IN clause, the below query is not optimized (doing full table scan). Please suggest alternate solutions.

```
select * from emp where ename in (
select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );
```

Comment: Add an explain plan and EMP table DDL to your question please.

Comment: What is the point of `connect by`? Without a `PRIOR` and `START WITH`, isn't it just a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: If you use a like 'SMITH%' it will likely invoke a btree index (unless the plan dictates otherwise), and you can drop the `dual`. Also, I agree with singron...  I'm not sure I follow why you have the connect by

Comment: What is the query plan?  What is the actual cardinality of the steps in the plan?  How do you know that a table scan is not the most efficient plan?  If it's not, that implies that either statistics on the table are incorrect or the optimizer's estimate of the number of rows your subquery returns is incorrect.  If the problem is the latter and you know (roughly) how many rows to expect, a `cardinality` hint might be appropriate.

Comment: A question like this with no supporting information is pointless. For instance - how many rows are there in your `EMP` table? Is a full table scan unreasonable in this situation? What indexes are available? What's the wall time for the current query? Will some other query plan offer better performance? (Not all full table scans are slow. In a small table where the entire table can be read in a few I/O's a full table scan may perform as well or better than an index search). What's the structure of the table? Partitioned/not partitioned? Thanks.

Comment: @singron - using `connect by` like this is a well-known technique for generating a rowset from fixed data.  In this case, it produces one row for each token in the string `'SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a proper index on `emp.ename`. 
**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE emp(id number(10) not null, ename varchar2(1024),
    CONSTRAINT emp_pk PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX emp_unique_index ON emp(ename);
```

This query doesn't do a full scan. See execution plan in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea484/1)

```
select * from emp
join (
select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) as name from dual
connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null 
) a on a.name = emp.ename
```

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax, not Oracle.  In Oracle, most commonly, you'd create and use a collection not a temporary table if you wanted to do this in multiple steps.  If you do that, however, there is a strong possibility that you'd need a cardinatlity hint

Comment: @Justin, agreed, in Oracle creating a temporary storage of that kind would not improve performance. However, it can give extra clarity when forming the filtering data. I will remove suggestion about temporary table from the answer